# Toggle Greet command for discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

I've made a code which greets new members in a particular channel but I want to toggle it.
If a staff member uses `!greet #channel` then **greet messages will be enabled in #channel**. And if they use `!greet`, it disables greet message for the server.

**GuildMemberAdd Event**

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name == 'welcome');
    if(!channel) return;
    channel.send(`Welcome to **${member.guild.name}**, ${member}!`)
    .then(message =>{
        message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

**More Info**

I just want to make it a toggle command and I'm not sure how to. I'd be glad for an early answer.

Answer (score 2):

So to toggle which channel will be send welcome message you need to store the channel ID somewhere like database or attach it with guild through collection [.set](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=set) . After that in your event before send message you get information from guild ID if it already set welcome channel so send message to that channel otherwise don't do anything

Comment: Okay let me try that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I would refer you to using db incase your bot restart and you will lose your setting if you .set()

Comment: Yup I'm using MongoDB and it works as needed. Thanks for the help ^-^